# How to disable user to access login/register page once they login?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, mern

How can I prevent the user to go to login page once they logged in, I've already managed to force the user to log in before accessing the home page, but I'm having a problem with, the user can still manage to login page even though he/she already login,

Protected.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import {Outlet, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

const Protected = ({children, ...rest}) => {
  const item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
  const token = item?.accessToken
  console.log(token)  

  return (
    token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
  )

}

export default Protected
```

App.js

```
function App() { 

  
 return(
  <Router>
    <Routes>
    
      <Route element={<Protected />}>
          <Route element={<Home />} path="/" exact />
          <Route path="/myproducts" element={ <MyProducts /> } />
          <Route path="/products/:category"  element={ <ProductContent />} />
          <Route path="/sell" element={ <Sell  />} />
          <Route path="/myproducts/" element={ <MyProducts /> } />
          <Route path="/singleproduct/:id" element={<SingleProduct />} />
          <Route path="/editproduct/:id" element={<EditProduct />} />
      </Route>

          <Route path="/register" element={ <Register />} />
          <Route element={<Login />} path="/login" />



    </Routes>
  <ToastContainer />
</Router>
 )
}

export default App
```

Comment: what version of react-router-dom your using ?

Comment: @Alpha react-router-domv6

Answer (score 1):

Create an anonymous route component that applies the inverse logic of the protected route component. If the user is already authenticated then bounce them to any non-"login" route.

```
const Anonymous = () => {
  const item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  const token = item?.accessToken;

  return token ? <Navigate to="/" replace /> : <Outlet />;
}
```

...

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<Protected />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/myproducts" element={<MyProducts />} />
      <Route path="/products/:category" element={<ProductContent />} />
      <Route path="/sell" element={<Sell />} />
      <Route path="/myproducts/" element={<MyProducts />} />
      <Route path="/singleproduct/:id" element={<SingleProduct />} />
      <Route path="/editproduct/:id" element={<EditProduct />} />
    </Route>
    <Route element={<Anonymous />}>
      <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Drew Reese, I can't tag you , I follow your recommendation

```
import React from 'react'
import {Outlet, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'

const Anonymous = () => {
    const item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
    const token = item?.accessToken
    console.log(token)  
  
    return (
      token ? <Navigate to="/" /> : <Outlet />
    )
}

export default Anonymous
```

Comment: Is there an issue with the implementation that you are asking for? Or, as a gentle reminder, instead of saying thanks or answering your question with a confirmation of the code solution there are optional actions you can take after [someone answers](/help/someone-answers).